# Load image for android

Tags: android, imageview

I'm loading a picture from the network for an ImageView but the imageView is not immediately showing up.

My code is:

```
protected void onStart() {
    iv_head.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_head));
    BaseController.getImageForUrl(HttpConstant.SERVER_HEAD + "/" +customer.getExtra().getLogo(), iv_head, R.drawable.default_head);
    super.onStart();
}

//获取图片的数据
public static void getImageForUrl(String url, final ImageView imageView, final int errorImage) {
    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(
           url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final Bitmap response) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
                    imageView.invalidate();
                }
            }, 0, 0, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   imageView.setImageResource(errorImage);
        }
    });
    QueueManager.getRequestQueue().add(imageRequest);
}
```

I'm sure that it is loading the Bitmap but ImageView is still giving problems.

If I click anywhere on the screen, then ImageView shows. Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: I dont know the cause of issue. but I have faced the same kind of issue. I solved this issue by putting imageview in scrollview. And after setting image to imageview I scrolled the view by 1 point.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(imageView.getResources(), response));
```

instead

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
imageView.invalidate();
```

Comment: I try to do as you say , but the effect is still the same.  I think that is not refreshed view problems.  However, I clicked on the screen just a point when the image is displayed immediately。

Comment: Your code looks pretty simple. The problem is not here.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library instead...then your code would be like this:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

nice and simple, no headaches, no reinvention of the wheel. Good luck!

Comment: I try to do as you say , but the effect is still the same. I think that is not refreshed view problems. However, I clicked on the screen just a point when the image is displayed immediately。